# EKS Kubernetes cannot list resource "namespaces" in API group "" at the cluster scope

Tags: kubernetes, amazon-eks

I have created kubernetes cluster using eks. 
Iam unable to create pod in worker node it showing some forbidden error (rbac).
while exploring I came to know that we have to change some authentication mode configuration in kube api server but in eks we can't get master config I think
So How to resolve this
can someone help?

Comment: how did you create the cluster? Is your kubectl configured correctly?

Comment: I created with aws eks console

Comment: have you configured your kubectl? `aws eks --region region-code update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name`

Comment: In worker node?

Comment: yes I have configured

Comment: no from your workstation or from the same machine that you are trying to deploy the pod.

Comment: Are you still facing the same issue?

Comment: yes, still facing this issue

Comment: Are you the person who created the cluster? by default, the person who created the cluster has the admin permission

Comment: yes I created the cluster

Comment: how are you trying to deploy a pod?

Comment: once nodegroup  is created I'm doing ssh to worker node and get login into that. there i have created pod file and i gave    kubectl apply -f pod_file.yml

Comment: no that's not how this typically works, you configure your workstation with the command `aws eks --region region-code update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name` and then run `kubectl apply -f pod_file.yaml`

Comment: yes Tried that also but still getting forbidden

Comment: Are you able to get the output of `kubectl describe configmap -n kube-system aws-auth`

Comment: No getting  like this  Error from server (Forbidden): configmaps "aws-auth" is forbidden: User "system:node:ip-xxx.region.compute.internal" cannot get resource "configmaps" in API group "" in the namespace "kube-system": no relationship found between node "ip-xxx.region.compute.internal" and this object

Comment: can you configure your aws keys and configure the kubeconfig once again, looks like it is not configured correctly, ideally it should be saying `User: your_username`

Comment: error: You must be logged in to the server (Unauthorized)
getting this exception now

Comment: configuring your awscli and kubectl correctly should ideally work for you.

Comment: working now Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

awscli and kubectl wasn't configured correctly

configuring awscli by running the command `aws configure` and then configuring kubectl by the command `aws eks --region region-code update-kubeconfig --name cluster_name` fixed the issue.